# Where is the location blue bar in iOS 11 beta 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, location, ios11

I have an app that is using always enabled location in the background and I don't see the blue bar as advertised in the latest beta. Do I have to build against the latest SDK for it to affect my app?

I also don't see it with Google Maps with location set to "always" and when navigating and that app in the background.

Thoughts?

Comment: I am wondering if because of the new screen layout for the new phone they have not put it in yet.

Comment: @solenoid, interesting theory. Note that the blue bar for "always" is still gone in beta 11.

Comment: I have downloaded public beta 5 and blue bar is appearing in my App. any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in beta 5, Apple has removed that blue status bar denoting the use of location. There has been no other replacement for it as of yet, it's just removed in beta 5.

[This link](https://9to5mac.com/2017/08/07/new-feature-in-ios-11-beta-5/)
to 9to5Mac discuss the same.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the CoreLocation Bar is not appearing in iOS 11.0b5 or 11.0b6.

This question falls into the problem of timeliness over Apple OS Beta releases. iOS 11.0 (as of the time of this asking) has not been released in final form to the public. As a result any and all features will be in flux until it is ultimately released.

There has been a lot of (searchable) public and developer pushback to the Core Location Blue Bar. (Often referred to in articles as the "Blue Bar of Shame")

Whether this is a change in direction for Apple from the precious 4 betas where it did appear, or a temporary adjustment is unknown. Release notes do not give guidance and there has not been any statement from Apple on the issue. Most importantly, conjecture will not do anything more than allow the individual some unnecessary "Head-Canon"

If you are a developer and have a strong opinion on the existence/removal of the bar; you need to file this through Apple's developer access to their radar system: http://bugreport.apple.com

Other than that; always use the latest versions of the SDK available, report any issues during beta phase, and wait for final release.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that the location bar is displayed when you select "While Using the App" from the location access. Its removed when you select "Always"

Comment: Indeed, which is the behaviour in <= iOS 10. Basically looks like they just backed it out.

Answer (score 0):

The Blue banner has been revoked in iOS beta 5. Linking back to another answer for more context.

[bluebar stays forever even if stopupdating is called in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109984/bluebar-stays-forever-even-if-stopupdating-is-called-in-ios-11/45727207#45727207)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84125